# pivot hinges on kitchen cabinet doors preventing removal for refurbish

Tags: hinges

help, trying to remove kitchen cabinets with pivot hinges and screws that are hidden on top by the top of the cabinet wall.  Is there a way to get at the top screws on a pivot hinge without demolishing the cabinet?

Comment: Could you post a picture?  My guess is that you can drill an access hole or , yes, you'll have to remove...

Answer (score 1):

If you are particularly interested in keeping the same door hinge system then it may become necessary to take down the cabinet sections where the hinges need to be removed. You already know that the cabinets were installed in a modular manner after they were built due the pivot hinge mounting. Taking down the cabinet would involve first emptying them out. Then search for screws inside the cabinet that go unto the wall studs behind the cabinet or screws that go up into the ceiling or cabinet soffit. In some cases there may be wood strip trim pieces along the cabinet edges against the wall or ceiling that need removing.

Answer (score 0):

A specialty tool might do the trick if it's just an inch or 2 from the ceiling. Don't worry they're cheap. A right angle screwdriver or a flexible sleeve for a power drill.

However, if you're starting at the top then you actually want to start at the bottom, if the door pin goes up into a cup. This means when you detach the bottom the door will just fall out & you never need to get involved with the top nor demolishing nor taking the cabinet down.